# The process cannot access the file 'Performance-5-2022.xlsx' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, interceptor, closedxml

I have a performance aspect method that logs how long it takes all services to respond.
I print the response times of all services to an excel file with closedxml.

When running in debug mode on my local computer, the application did not cause any problems, but when I run it on my plesk server, I get the following error.

> The process cannot access the file
> '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/api.domain.com/Log/Performance-5-2022.xlsx'
> because it is being used by another process.

```
public class PerformanceAspect : MethodInterception
    {
        private int _interval;
        private Stopwatch _stopwatch;

        public PerformanceAspect(int interval)
        {
            _interval = interval;
            _stopwatch = ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService<Stopwatch>();
        }

        protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            _stopwatch.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnAfter(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var contentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var today = DateTime.Now;

            var xlsxName = "Performance-" + today.Month + "-" + today.Year + ".xlsx";

            var fileLocation = contentRoot + "/Log/" + xlsxName;

            var fileExists = File.Exists(fileLocation);

            if (_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > _interval)
            {
                // Debug.WriteLine($"Performance : {invocation.Method.DeclaringType.FullName}.{invocation.Method.Name}--->{_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

                using (var workbook = fileExists ? new XLWorkbook(fileLocation) : new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var worksheet = fileExists ? workbook.Worksheet(1) : workbook.Worksheets.Add("Performance");
                    var currentRow = fileExists ? worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber() : 1;

                    if (fileExists == false)
                    {

                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "FullName";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Method";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = "Date";
                        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = "TotalSeconds";

                    }


                    currentRow++;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = invocation.Method.DeclaringType.FullName;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = invocation.Method.Name;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = today.ToString();
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

                    workbook.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                }

            }

            _stopwatch.Reset();
        }
    }
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using Excel this way won't work. The process is slow enough that if two requests are made close to each other they'll try to open, modify and write the same file. Use a text file instead. There's a reason logs are stored in text files - appending a new line to a file is almost instantaneous. In fact, what you want to do is already supported in a far better way by ASP.NET Core itself

Comment: .NET Core [already supports metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-collection) using various APIs. One of them is through OpenTelemetry, a standard used for tracing and monitoring distributed services. Metrics can be logged to files or pushed to eg Prometheus. An [ASP.NET Core instrumentation library](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore) is already available

Comment: I prefer it because it is easier to calculate with Excel. In this way, I can reach the average response time of the services and similar performance requests.

Comment: For testing purposes, try to call `worksheet.Dispose();  workbook.Dispose();` after `workbook.SaveAs` See whether it helps to close the file. so when you try to open the file you will not get the above error message. Further, before opening a file you could add logic to check whether the file is already open or not. It may help to avoid the above error.